# how make instance group members work behind behind loadbalancer only

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, vpc

I am able to make work the backend service as an instance group - if i enable the "Allow http access" enabled while creating the members in the instance group.

However i want to disable this and make the network work only from the loadbalancer(external ip). However it is not working. The way I did was to define a firewall rule in the subnet where the instance group is there, such that the destination is the network tags defined for the instance group members

[settings link as iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S10Ay.png)

the source is dfined as the ip of the load balancer as a range.

Comment: What kind of Load Balancer are you using? You should do something like this: HTTPS Load balancer -> Instance group internal IP pool, (network tags in the instance group and a firewall rule that allow the ingress traffic from the load balancer to the tag int port 443 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create VPC Firewall rules that only allow traffic from the load balancer and health check service.

- 130.211.0.0/22
- 35.191.0.0/16
- 34.96.0.0/20
- 34.127.192.0/18

References:

- [Firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#firewall_rules)
- [Configuring a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-https-lb-simple#firewall)

Answer (score 0):

Where you looking is fine, you can do it.
The steps are, as I suggested in my comment a little bit more, I will resume them in this list, and let you the link of a qwiklab, you can check the steps there with the code to do it by yourself.

Basically:

1. Create the instances or instance group with the corresponding healtcheck.
2. Configure the Load balancer
3. Set the traffic to the new loadbalancer and build the proxy.
4. Create HTTPS Load Balancer and send the traffic to the Proxy.

https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/12007?catalog_rank=%7B%22rank%22%3A1%2C%22num_filters%22%3A0%2C%22has_search%22%3Atrue%7D&parent=catalog&search_id=15082883

I think that the link is creating instance by instance, but the steps should be the same for an instance group.